# How to turn on and off an elan touchpad from the command line in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

I would like to use a batch file command to turn my Elan touchpad on and off in my Windows 10 HP x2

Comment: Look into [DevCon Disable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-disable)

Comment: Download potentially from here: https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/e/4/6e481b67-54af-4340-a534-25de4229cfc6/support.cab